# Why the column generation algorithm remains stuck at the same solution?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, cplex, column-generation

I was trying to solve a MILP by a column generation algorithm, and I noticed that the algorithm was stuck at the same solution, I tried to diversify the pool of initial columns, but the problem I faced was that even if the MP solved by CPLEX gave the optimal solution, the algorithm cannot prove it and keep returning it.

Comment: It's not clear what "the algorithm cannot prove it and keep returning it" means. Do you mean that you find a column with negative reduced cost that is already in the column pool? If yes, what is the value of the reduced cost?

Comment: Does the subproblem keep returning new columns with negative reduced cost?

Comment: Yeah, the subproblem keeps returning new columns. I solved the problem instance exactly using CPLEX in 1 second, but when calling column generation even if the Master Problem returns this solution from the first iteration, the subproblem keeps returning columns with negative reduced cost for many hours (I set 5 hours as limit time).

Comment: Does your subproblem objective maybe include a constant offset that you are not accounting for?  It might be best to show us your original, master, and subproblem formulations (in math, not in code).

Comment: If at least one of the columns that you add at each iteration was not in the pool and ends up in the master problem solution of the next iteration, then it''s just that the algorithm hasn't converge yet. For large problems, the column generation procedure might require a lot of iterations

Comment: Does "same solution" mean same objective value or the same values for all variables (which would mean the new variables are taking value 0 in the solution)?

Comment: @prubin the both meanings.

Comment: Is it the solution to the LP relaxation of the master problem that stays the same, or are you solving the master as an integer program?

Comment: The problem was solved as an integer program, and the LP relaxation was used to extract the dual values for the subproblems. Even if the solution stays the same I noticed that the dual values keep changing. Including some heuristics in the framework made an improvement and restuck at a local optimal. I think that it is just a problem of convergence regarding the complexity of the problem.

Comment: You might try using an interior point algorithm (without crossover) for the master LP solve.  This simple idea sometimes helps column generation to converge more quickly.

Comment: I attempted to address the main issue by applying the interior point method (barrier) without crossover from CPLEX to solve the master problem. However, I did not observe any noticeable improvements in the results.

Comment: Upon analyzing the tests, the pricing problem was not effectively fulfilling its role. It came to my attention that the complexity of the problem (a Vehicle Routing Problem) stems from the fact that a customer is not necessarily served, which makes it more challenging to identify the most suitable set of customers to be served. Consequently, in each iteration, the customers included remain identical to those present in the initial columns.

Comment: If you are using a set partitioning master problem with an $=1$ constraint for each customer node, you might instead try a set covering master that replaces $=1$ with $\ge 1$.

Comment: I used a set covering master with $\leq 1$. Because each customer is served at most once. And I added a constraint to ensure that the number of rejected customers does not exceed a given threshold.

Comment: OK, $\le 1$ is set packing. I recommend instead set covering ($\ge 1$), which guarantees to cover each customer at least once. At optimality, customers will naturally be covered exactly once.